# Rails 3.1 beta installation hangs because of mime-types gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I get the following failure whilst trying to install rails3.1.beta on ubuntu10.10

```
gem install mime-types
Fetching: mime-types-1.16.gem ( 97%)ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    too many connection resets (http://production.cf.rubygems.org/gems/mime-types-1.16.gem)
```

Anyone else seeing this?

Using latest rubygems 1.8.3 and ruby 1.9.2p180 and I've installed all the dependencies for the mime-types gem (i.e. hoe, rcov, nokogiri, archive-tar-minitar)

rubygems.org does say that mime-types is the second most downloaded gem today with over 5000 dl's - I've tried to isntall several times and it keeps hanging at 97%, everytime

Comment: is that the full stack trace? (er, I'm assuming it's not but for the sake of not assuming I still ask:). Sometimes the gem install errors mask some deeper issue--a missing library, failure to sacrifice a chicken, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the [mime-types](http://mime-types.rubyforge.org/) gem?  That seems to be an old gem - isnt the [mime type stuff](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html) built into Rails sufficient?